# Dropdown navigation menu appears besides the element

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a dropdown menu which appears to be working with some success but the catch is...It presents the dropdown menu on the right side of the element instead of directly under it.
I suspect it has something to do with either position or padding but I wasn't able to figure it out.
Thanks for taking a look, I'm still new to css and it means a lot!

html

```
    <nav id="navigatie" class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <li><a href="html/producten.html">Producten</a></li>
        <li><a href="html/personaliseren.html">Personaliseren</a></li>
        <li><a>Over ons</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="html/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
html {
    background: #936A4A;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #F5F5F5;

}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    width: 25%;
}

ul li > ul {
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li > ul li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    flex: auto;

}

li a {
    color: #B85750;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
    pointer-events: none
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to position the submenu absolutely in relation to the parent `li`.

```css
html {
  background: #936A4A;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  /* display: none; */
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li:hover>ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li>ul li {
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
}

li a {
  color: #B85750;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigatie" class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
      <li><a href="html/producten.html">Producten</a></li>
      <li><a href="html/personaliseren.html">Personaliseren</a></li>
      <li><a>Over ons</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="html/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="html/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following solution.

```css
html {
          background: #fff;
        }
            
        .parent-container{
            position: relative;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
            
        nav {
            background: #F5F5F5;
        }


        ul { 
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        li {
            background: #936A4A; 
            display: block;
            float: left;
            padding: 1rem;
            position: relative;
            text-decoration: none;
            transition-duration: 0.5s;
        }

        li a {
          color: #fff;
        }

        li:hover {    
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        ul li ul {    
          visibility: hidden;
          opacity: 0;
          min-width: 5rem;
          position: absolute;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
          margin-top: 1rem;
          left: 0;
          display: none;
          background: lightblue;
        }

        ul li:hover > ul,
        ul li ul:hover {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
          display: block;
        }

        ul li ul li {
          clear: both;
          width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>        
        <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-container">
        <nav role="navigation" class="nav" id="navigatie">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <li><a href="html/producten.html">Producten</a></li>
            <li><a href="html/personaliseren.html">Personaliseren</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Over ons</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="html/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="html/faq.html">FAQ</a>/<li>
              </ul>
            </li>   
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```